# what are specified value, computed value, and actual value?

Tags: css

English isn't my first language so I find it hard to learn from MDN.

I think from what i read a specified value is a style that was specified in a style sheet or a style that was inherited from a parent element.

I dont really know what a computed value is

An actual value is the value that is actually used

Comment: @Teocci did you read the question before adding that comment?

Comment: 1/ No translation in your first language? MDN has contributors for translations in a few languages but yeah it's more active in french than in hindi or suomi :) 2/ You may found a recent article by Greg Whitworth in ALA useful: [Braces to pixels](https://alistapart.com/article/braces-to-pixels). It talks about parsing, computing, layout and the value `auto`, CSS Object Model, formatting context, specificity, etc but with just enough details and not too much IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can look as if those values are all the same; i.e. specified, computed and actual values all being 1px, and you can't see any differences and you wonder why there are so many phrases to describe the same thing!
So maybe some examples will make it clear.

The *specified value* is whatever you specify. For instance, if you write `p {font-size:2rem;` in your stylesheet, then the specified value for `p` is `2rem`, obviously.

Then the browser computes what that is in pixels, which is (at least if 1rem is 16px) `32px`. That is the *computed value*, which is used for display (so it's also the *used value*, and in most cases also the *actual value*).

However, there are some circumstances where 32px is not possible. For example if this particular font is a bitmapped font, and a 32px version is not available. If there is only a 30px version, then that is what is actually put on the display as the *actual value*.

The *used value* can also differ from the *computed value*. For example, if you have `p {width:600px; max-width:400px;}` in your stylesheet, then the *computed value* will be still be `600px`, but the *used value* (and therefore the *actual value*) will be `400px`.

Hope this helps. If you need more examples, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what the values to me!

Comment: Is there any way to get used value? For example, `getComputedStyle()` on an inline element returns a `margin-top` of `"100px"` (the specified value), but I want to get `"0px"`. Granted the specified value is used in browser inspect (it just not push other elements vertically).

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Interesting. The formal answer is that inline elements don't _have_ a vertical margin, so you can't say the margin is 0; it's simply not applicable. Just like, e.g., inline elements don't have `border-spacing`, so you can't say the border-spacing is 0.

Comment: We all agree that inline doesn't *have* vertical margin, but the word *have* itself may be open to interpretation. For example, DevTool still reports that my span has vertical margins, just not displayed/ignored somehow. Take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271376/how-to-get-html-element-actual-used-style-value), a comment also uses the term *collapsing* for the absence of vertical margin.

Comment: if `p { width: 20px; }`, is `20px` specified value, computed value and actual value? As such`20px` value, always need to computed(I mean it is both specified value and computed value)?? @MrLister

Comment: @OnlyWick With `px`, yes, the computed value is the specified value. For other units such as `ch`, the computed value will be the value in pixels. The _actual_ value however, may differ, depending on other things, like `max-width` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

**Specified value:**

Specified values are values which are provided and not generated.
For example
Inheriting from external css file

Inheriting the value of the parent element

Using the initial value of property

**Computed Value:**
Computed values are the values which are calculated when relative positioning or values are used. For ex `width:20%` is to be calculated in reference to the parent .

**Actual Value:**
Ready to be used values are actual values.Absolute values like `font:10pt` is an actual /absolute value it doesn't depend on other values.

Answer (score -2):

The computed value is the value inherited from another element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value

Comment: The questioner told in his/her question that he/she finds it hard to learn from MDN ! He/She asked for your answer in easy language not the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) link !